# Azure- update function code in Function App using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I want to update the code in one of the functions in my `Function App` using CLI.
I can't find the appropriate command to do so using `az functionapp`.
What is the best wat yo do this, not using the portal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update Function App , you can use the [`CLI command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-update),

```
az functionapp update --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

However best practice is to automate by using [Azure Devops](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurefunctions/) or [`GithubActions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-github-actions?tabs=javascript)

Comment: Thanks, how can I specify the new function I want to set using "az functionapp update"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#publish):

```
func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>
```